# Powershell remote exchange session missing types

Tags: powershell, session, exchange-server

I'd like to collect and process some data from Exchange on remote server using powershell script. Script will be executed on host A, it will create session to host B, inside this session it will create another session - to exchange endpoint.
I'm doing it this way for security reasons, Exchange session needs to be created locally. The issue is that my first session doesn't have exchange data types, type of my $data object
is PSObject, but it should be MailboxDatabase. Is there a way to somehow import data types needed?

```
$sessWsman = GetOrCreateSession $ip $login $uri $password $configurationName $retryConnectUsingFdqn $uriTemplate $macroMissingWindowsCredentials $macroUnableConnect $macroSessionsDepleted $macroSessionClosed $null

Invoke-Command -Session $sessWsman -Args @("ENG-AUS-SAM-11") -ScriptBlock {

    $sessExchange = GetOrCreateSession $ip $login $uri $password $configurationName $retryConnectUsingFdqn $uriTemplate $macroMissingWindowsCredentials $macroUnableConnect $macroSessionsDepleted $macroSessionClosed $sessWsman

    if ( -Not ([bool](Get-Command -Name 'Get-MailboxDatabase' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)))
    {
        Import-PSSession $sessExchange -FormatTypeName * -CommandName Get-MailboxDatabase | Out-null
    }

    $data = Get-MailboxDatabase -Server $HostName -Status

    $data.GetType()
}
```

I tried adding this `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange*` after importing `Get-MailboxDatabase`, but it didn't helped.